# how can i use LVL for creating a time limited version (trial version) of an app

Tags: android, android-lvl

i want to create a trial version app, but i couldn't find how to limit the app usage for a fixed time (say 15 days).

Is it possible using android LVL?

Comment: anybody know how to implement a ServerManagedPolicy for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you read the [second answer of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877311/lvl-behavior-on-client-side-license-validity-check-for-free-apps/5810198#5810198).

I don't think you can and should want to release a free version with the same package as a future paid version : you won't be able to do so.

But the *right* solution, to my mind, is a different package with an other kind of security check that prevents the app from working after some time.

You want people to download freely your app then you have no choice exept saying your app is free, for every one, but this could be for a limited trial period (i.e berfor june 15)

Otherwise, I don't see how you could do to let people download it for free AND pay for licence.

Remember that if you choose to make a free app :

- this leads a server policy manager to send a huge number as validity time stamp for the licence checker.
- thus, when your app will become paid then you will never be able to say if your first users of free version converted... LVL will let your free users run the free version.

I  kind of think something should be feasible by re writing a server managed policy and changing the validity when receiving it from server, but it seems to me LVL has not been meant for that and it would be a pity to loose some revenues...
Here is [the code for servermanager](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/ServerManagedPolicy.java), you could attempt to override setValidityTimestamp and give it an upper limit if licence is given for free.

But, again, the *right* solution, to my mind is a different package with an other kind of security check that prevents the app from working after some time.

Steff

Comment: a different package name is acceptable for me. but i don't know how can i do this with a different package name. pls tell me what type of security check i need to add, so that app will stop working after some days.