# How to restrict my android app to get published other than google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way android provides to restrict my custom application to get it published other than Google play store? And this app will not be a paid app so I can't use LVL feature and as per below discussion, we can't publish free app with licensing check:

**[LVL behavior on client side license validity check for free apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877311/lvl-behavior-on-client-side-license-validity-check-for-free-apps)**

So, not able to find any ways to restrict it to publish my free app to other stores :(.

**Why I want to restrict it to publish it to other stores:**

Because any hackers can download your app from google play store and inject malware in it and publish infected app to other stores.

Please provide me the guidelines to achieve it.

Comment: If they can "inject malware in it" then they can remove anything you add to protect it as well.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter.  If you're worried about someone injecting malware into your APK just think-  they can just as easily lie, say that they're your app, and upload pure malware. They don't actually need to be your app.

Comment: can't we restrict to publish the app to other stores by any means?

Answer (score 2):

Beat them to it. Publish your app on the alternative app stores so that when they try to upload the package name is already taken by your original, clean version.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Get the installer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10809481/2431281) when your app opens and check if it is from Google Play by comparing it to `com.android.vending`. If it is not, block any use of the app.

But of course hackers can still download your app, remove this kind of security and upload it to other stores. But I guess this can give you an idea? Also Gabe Sechan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522953/2431281) is possible too.

Comment: can't we restrict to publish the app to other stores by any means?